# Detect eye movement in a thermal video using python opencv

Tags: image, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

How to detect eye movement, when it's closed. I am able to detect the closed eye region in a thermal video with finding the hottest spot then drawn a circle around that point.with the trial and error i was roughly able to estimate the eye corner co-ordinates then i cropped out the eye region[2] from the video. The next task is to detect its movement.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter
blur_radius = 1.0
threshold = 50


video = cv2.VideoCapture('12.avi')
while True:
        ret, frame = video.read()
        frame = frame[:,1:600]
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15,15), 0)
        (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
        image = frame
        (x,y) = maxLoc
        cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, 15, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(image,(maxLoc),(390,190),(0,255,0),2)
        roi = frame [y:190,x:390]
        try:
                roi = cv2.resize(roi, None, fx=4, fy=4, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                cv2.imshow("Eye",roi)
                cv2.imshow("Eyecorner", image)
        except:
                print''

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: 1][1]
[image: 2][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jayfp.jpg  = detected eye in a single frame

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgEe7.jpg = the cropped eye region from a thermal video

Comment: Perhaps use *eigenimages* of open and closed eyes and look if it bounces between them?

Comment: Actually the eye lid is closed all the time, I have to calculate the eye movement in sleep state i.e to verify if the eye ball is moving inside the closed lids.

Comment: well I don't know that much about eye movement when sleeping. Do you see that on the screen? How? That should be the first question you have to answer: "how can I do that myself".

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning it earlier. In a thermal video you can see the eyeball movement even when the eyelid is closed. but i don't know how to detect that rapid movement.

Comment: Can you share some video sequence? Without knowing how significant the movement is it's hard to give good answer.

Comment: I have the video files but i don't how to share here [link](https://giphy.com/gifs/5QYskmKIcddXG) this is a gif  of video and the video i currently working on is 9 fps

Comment: To be honest I don't see eye movement in that gif.

Comment: There is a very slight movement in the eye lashes, which indicate that the eyeball is moving behind the eyelid it provides information about the sleep state of an individual

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the hotspot containing the eye and the coordinates of the eye corners, can't you simply measure the distance between the center of the hotspot and the center point between the two corners at every frame and examine its rate of change? You didn't mention how precise the measurements are, but provided that they are 100% correct and that the head doesn't move too much (perspective doesn't change), then it should work. Otherwise you need another way to determine a frame of reference.

Comment: Hotspot varies when there is a little tilt in the face,as there are two eye corners with same pixel values respectively the rectangle around the eye region shifts. And the method you proposed gives me the movement of face but not the eye, it calculates rate of change in face.